# Running app not possible after manual deinstallation

Tags: android, android-studio

After deinstalling my app manually from the phone I get this error when I try to debug/run the app via Android Studio: 03/03 19:24:49:

```
Launching 'app' on HUAWEI ANE-LX1.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.projectname/com.example.projectname.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.projectname/com.example.projectname.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.projectname/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.projectname/com.example.projectname.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

On my emulatated devices it is still running. Any ideas how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Studio is unaware that the app has been uninstalled and is trying to launch it without reinstalling, probably because you haven't made any changes. I would recommend using the "Invalidate Caches / Restart" menu option in Studio (in the File Menu) to clear the caches Studio uses in builds and restart the program. If that fails, try restarting the target device as well as running the `clean` task from gradle.

Comment: Both was not working. I opened the project on another computer and got the message: "The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.". After pressing "OK" i managed to install it again.

Comment: With that error, it sounds like the app wasn't properly uninstalled from the phone or that you had multiple copies of the app installed somehow. If you've been able to get a fresh install since then, you *should* be set, but if it keeps happening you may have to look into how to remove the app completely if the system is failing to do so when you manually uninstall.